# GetProcessAffinityMask returns null process affinity

Tags: c++, c, winapi

In a very simple test console application, I tried to get process' affinity mask:

**EDIT** This code is incorrect. Problem solved. Please check comments and validated answer.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        DWORD dwProcessAffinityMask = 0;
        DWORD dwSystemAffinityMask = 0;

        BOOL res = GetProcessAffinityMask(
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            (PDWORD_PTR)&dwProcessAffinityMask,
            (PDWORD_PTR)&dwSystemAffinityMask);

        printf("%d 0x%X 0x%X\n",
            res,
            dwProcessAffinityMask,
            dwSystemAffinityMask);

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output (64-bit executable, 64-bit system, meaning I do not fall into the WoW64 special case):

```
1 0x0 0x3
1 0x0 0x3
...
```

Running on my laptop, which has a 2 cores CPU, the resulting system's mask looks correct. But I don't understand the meaning of the `dwProcessAffinityMask` value I get here. Just for the sake of it, I also tried to toy around with the *Task Manager* by changing the process' affinity mask but the output remains the same.

This behavior doesn't seem to be [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683213(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You are supposed to pass a pointer to a `DWORD_PTR`, not a to a `DWORD`.

Comment: Damn, you're right! I am a chimp! The test works properly now.

Comment: What made you write `(PDWORD_PTR)` without thinking "hmm, maybe this is wrong, I should check it carefully"?

Comment: @immibis I have been confused by this DWORD_PTR vs. LPDWORD_PTR thing while reading the doc. Also, the original code comes from a 32bit application which is the reason why this bug never showed up before porting it to 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the address of `DWORD_PTR` variables rather than `DWORD` variables.

```
DWORD_PTR dwProcessAffinityMask;
DWORD_PTR dwSystemAffinityMask;
```

And remove those casts. They were a clear indication of what was wrong. When the compiler reports that you are passing parameters whose types don't match, correct the types rather than suppressing the error. The compiler already told you what was wrong, you just need to learn how to interpret its messages.

Comment: I mostly certainly have to remember not to copy/paste code from a third party without actually reviewing it. Thanks!